# E: Problem syncing the file - sync (30: Read-only file system)

Tags: sync

I have successfully installed Ubuntu Server 15.10 on EXTERNAL Western Digital HDD.

Trying to update using apt-get update, getting the error:

```
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Translation-en
Fetched 1,405 kB in 19s (70.3 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Problem syncing the file - sync (30: Read-only file system)
E: Write error - write (30: Read-only file system)
E: IO Error saving source cache
E: Problem renaming the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin.iln136 to 
/var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - rename (30: Read-only file system)
E: Failed to truncate file - ftruncate (30: Read-only file system)
E: Problem renaming the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin.dd4Dng to 
/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - rename (30: Read-only file system)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I have tried:

```
sudo mount -o rw,remount /
```

Results:

```
mount: cannot remount /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected
```

Also:

```
sudo fsck -Af -M
```

And

```
mount -o remount /
```

Results:

```
mount: cannot remount /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

**Update**

Cannot reboot:
[Cannot reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIk6L.jpg)

After manually force shutdown
[Cannot lunch ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdWUi.jpg)

After manually fsck, now system is opened successfully but still cannot update:

```
Fetched 1,405 kB in 42s (33.2 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ams2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu                                                                                                                     /dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
```

Many of it...

Comment: Actually everything is now not accessible, all system is totally read-only, cannot even edit file by nano. 
    Unable to create directory /root/.nano: Read-only file system
It is required for saving/loading search history or cursor positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forcing fsck manually to lunch Ubuntu:

[fsck manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHar5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect this HDD to another working system. Then edit yout fstab file on HDD (mount all partitions with rw permissions).
Also you may have this problem if your external HDD have hardware button with access/backup or programable functions. In this case you must unlock or disable security on HDD first.

Comment: Thanks for response, I was able to open system again by manually fsck but still cannot update, getting error:
 W: Failed to fetch http://ams2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu                                                                                                     /dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  
Hash Sum mismatch

Comment: Delete this repo.  You can find it at /etc/apt/sources. list or /etc/apt/sources.list.d/  . Then delete file which complies your repo from /var/lib/apt/lists . This file has different HASH sum . For example file for skype repo :

Comment: Package: skype
Priority: extra
Section: net
Installed-Size: 61
Maintainer: Steve Langasek <steve.langasek@canonical.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
Depends: skype-bin
Filename: pool/partner/s/skype/skype_4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
Size: 16054
MD5sum: 61d508cabddd6d9ef7bc9967eb4bb2ed
SHA1: 590099bbcc9c486cf92b035d534fab0b062edd4e
SHA256: 590e13cf75d75cd94ddc33af179588654b5c7c0933b585e5e118e07143c96748
Description: client for Skype VOIP and instant messaging service
Description-md5: a398bc8cee97c4027d64bae3fa223f58

Comment: Then use sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update. Then add your repo and sync